# Why can't I render list of related product in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, api, list, data

**Problem** : I have to display a list of products related to a package (which is related to an order), but I have 2 issues:

1. Only one element of the list is displaying
2. It's displaying the same element in all the packages linked to the same order

I have use for:each to display the list of packages related to the same order and it's working, but it does not for the product component.

Here's my code:

Parent Component html:

```
<template if:true={doDetails}>

<template for:each={doDetails} for:item="doDetail">
  <lightning-accordion allow-multiple-sections-open
                           onsectiontoggle={handleSectionToggle}
                           active-section-name={activeSections}
                           key={doDetail.doNbr}>

  <lightning-accordion-section name="A" label="Package" >

<div class="slds-form" role="list" >
    <div class="slds-form__row">
      <div class="slds-form__item" role="listitem">
        <div class="slds-form-element slds-form-element_readonly slds-form-element_horizontal slds-hint-parent">
          <span class="slds-form-element__label">
            Status</span>
          <div class="slds-form-element__control">
            <div class="slds-form-element__static">
              {doDetail.doFulfillmentStatus}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
    </div>  

   <template for:each={doLineItems} for:item="doLineItem">
  <c-ic-product-details get-do-nbr={keyDoNbr} key={doLineItem.orderLineId}></c-ic-product-details>
</template>

</lightning-accordion-section>

</lightning-accordion>
</template>
</template>
```

Parent Component js:

```
import { LightningElement, track, api } from 'lwc';
import getCustomerOrder from '@salesforce/apex/ctrlCustomerOrder.getCustomerOrder';

export default class IcPackageInformation extends LightningElement {
@track displayPopup = false;
@track doDetails;
@track doLineItems;
@api keyDoNbr;

connectedCallback(){
    this.fetchOrderDetails();
}
fetchOrderDetails(){
    let customerOrderNumber = 'xxxxxx';

    getCustomerOrder({customerOrderNumber:customerOrderNumber})
    .then(data => {
        let objData={
            doDetails:'',
            
        };

        this.doDetails = data.doDetails;

        this.doDetails.forEach(doDetail =>{
            for(let i = 0; i < doDetail.doLineItems.length; i++){
            this.keyDoNbr = doDetail.doLineItems[i].doNbr;
            this.doLineItems = doDetail.doLineItems;
            }
        })    

    }).catch(error => {
        window.console.log('callout error ', JSON.stringify(error));

    })
}

}
```

Child Component js:

```
import { LightningElement, track, api } from 'lwc';
import getCustomerOrder from '@salesforce/apex/ctrlCustomerOrder.getCustomerOrder';

export default class IcProductDetails extends LightningElement {
@track displayPopup = false;
@track doDetails;
@track doLineItems;
@api getDoNbr;

handleClick(event) {
    this.template.querySelector('a').click();
    this.displayPopup = true;
}

connectedCallback(){
    this.fetchOrderDetails();
}

fetchOrderDetails(){
    let customerOrderNumber = 'xxxxxx';

    getCustomerOrder({customerOrderNumber:customerOrderNumber})
    .then(data => {
        let objData={
            doDetails:'',
            doLineItems: ''

        };
                for(let i = 0; i < data.doDetails.length; i++){
                    this.doDetails = data.doDetails;

                    for(let j = 0; j < data.doDetails[i].doLineItems.length; j++){
                        this.doLineItems = data.doDetails[i].doLineItems[j];                  
                    }                
                }          

        }).catch(error => {
            window.console.log('callout error ', JSON.stringify(error));

        })
}

}
```

Did I miss a step to render the list of related products ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are re-assigning the `doDetails` list each time you loop - which needs only to be done once.

Also you are overwriting the `doLineItems` list each time in the loop - you want to `push` the items rather than assign them.

Like this:

```
//do this to avoid invoking unnecessary binding in the loop
let tempLineItems = [];
data.doDetails.forEach( doDetail => {
  tempLineItems.push(...doDetail.doLineItems)
});
this.doLineItems = tempLineItems;
this.doDetails = data.doDetails;
```

Also, note the `spread` (`...`) operator, which literally spreads out an array - and allows you to call `push` just once per group of line items.

I'm not sure what this is for btw:

```
let objData={
  doDetails:'',
   doLineItems: ''
};
```

I can't see it used anywhere. Maybe you can remove it.

Comment: ok thanks, it did helped me a lot ! I still have the issue of relating each product lines to the right package, but working on it